# Display Image on xAxis in highchart

Tags: image, highcharts

i have total 10 category in xAxis and i want to display category icon in xAxis accroding to category so please tell me how to possible to display icon in xAxis in highchart .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use `formatter` for the labels in combination with `useHTML: true`.

For example:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.value == "Jun")
                return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />'+this.value;
            else if(this.value == "Dec")
                 return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />'+this.value;
            else
                return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/sz6joexy/).